# mb_ereg_match使用して全角スペースのみで構成された文字列をNGとするにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？

Tags: php, 正規表現

PHP 7.3.9 利用していて、コード上で mb_ereg_matchの関数が動くことは確認しております。

文字列のチェックをしたいのですが、全角スペースのみで構成された文字列のときfalseを返すにはどうしたら良いでしょうか？

1. "　" ← 全角スペースが1つ
2. "　　" ← 全角スペースが2つ以上続く
3. "　あいうえおabc" ← 全角スペースが1つあった後に、全角スペース以外の任意の文字列が1文字以上続く
4. "　　あいうえおabc" ← 全角スペースが2つ以上続いた後に、全角スペース以外の任意の文字列が1文字以上続く
5. "あ　いうえおabc" ← 任意の文字列が1文字以上続き、間に全角スペースも1文字以上含まれる
6. "あいうえおabc" ← 任意の文字列が1文字以上続き、全角スペースは含まれない

上記の1〜6で言うと1,2の場合にのみfalseとなるイメージです。
どなたかご教授いただけましたら幸いです。すみませんがよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 前提条件の話なんですけどmb_ereg_matchを使わなきゃいけないのでしょうか？例えば全角スペースを半角スペースに変換してtrimをかけて文字長が0になったらfalseを返すとかではだめですか？

Comment: `!(Not operator)` を使って `!mb_ereg_match('^\u3000+$', $word)` など。

Comment: @keitaro_so ありがとうございます！mb_ereg_matchを使わなければいけない訳ではないのですが、全角文字を扱う文字列検索ということで最初に思いついたものがそれでした。。。「全角スペースを半角スペースに変換して〜」の方がもしかすると処理速度は速いのかもですね。試してみます！mm

Comment: @metropolis ありがとうございます！！そうですね、"!" 使えばいけそうですね・・・正規表現の理解も浅く、近いところまでは行ってたんですが最後に$マーク付けるのを忘れて右往左往しておりました（＾＾；　単純な質問＆勉強不足ですみません。こちらも試してみますね！mm